# Slider control for volume - JQuery/Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am looking for a fancy Slider control using JQuery/Javascript. The native JQuery slider is rather bland for this requirement. The slider will be used to specify the volume in the increments of 5. So, this slider should only let user slide in increments of 5.

One nice to have feature is to be able to show label above the slider position indicating what volume the user has selected.

Comment: Whatever you use, be sure to take the logarithm for the final volume multiplier.

Comment: @Mark - could you go into more detail on that? I'm curious to know what you mean.

Comment: What's wrong with the jQuery UI slider exactly?  You mention it's "too bland" but it meets every requirement...knowing what's wrong with it would help.

Comment: Can I display a label on the top of the slider selection using the jquery slider? Can I set an image as the background? Can I change the appearance of the slider?

Comment: Yes to all of the above, posted an answer with examples and links for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's an example of the [customization you're after](http://www.filamentgroup.com/lab/update_jquery_ui_slider_from_a_select_element_now_with_aria_support//) that uses the [jQuery UI Slider](http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#slider-vertical).  It's all CSS in the background, you can customize the hell out of it.

Setting the snap you can do increments and update the amount like this:

```
$("#mySlider").slider({
      orientation: "vertical",
      range: "min",
      min: 0,
      max: 100,
      step: 5,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
           $("#amount").val(ui.value);
      }
 });
$("#amount").val($("#mySlider").slider("value"));
```

Answer (score 2):

I've found a nice volume slider. I think this is what you're looking for. It's the classic triangle-shaped controller with increasing vertical bars. And it's very customizable with position indicator. Download the zip file here: http://ruwix.com/javascript-volume-slider-control/